# django crispy forms - how to group the fields?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

My form is here:

```
class SortFieldsForm(forms.Form):
    LatestyearModel=forms.BooleanField(label="latest year")
    LowestPrice=forms.BooleanField(label="lowest price")
    HighestPrice=forms.BooleanField(label="highest price")
    Newest_Entry=forms.BooleanField(label="latest date")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'sort_posting'

        #self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(SortFieldsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            #Fieldset(
            #    'price',
            #    'LowestPrice',
            #    'HighestPrice',
             ),
            PrependedText('LowestPrice', ''),
            PrependedText('HighestPrice', ''),
            PrependedText('Newest_Entry', ''),
            PrependedText('LatestyearModel', ''),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )
```

Currently the form shows as this:
[image]

I want to group lowest price and highest price in one radioselect,
latest date and latest year as checkboxes neatly aligned with submit button next to the field. Not below them as it currently now.

Any pointers/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
class SortFieldsForm(forms.Form):
    LatestyearModel=forms.BooleanField(label="latest year")
    LowestPrice=forms.BooleanField(label="lowest price")
    HighestPrice=forms.BooleanField(label="highest price")
    Newest_Entry=forms.BooleanField(label="latest date")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'sort_posting'

        #self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(SortFieldsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper.layout = Layout(

            'LowestPrice',
            'HighestPrice',
            'Newest_Entry',
            'LatestyearModel' ,
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ChoiceField` and `MultipleChoiceField` with labels and custom widgets `RadioSelect` and `CheckboxSelectMultiple`.

**More explanation**

First, some code. I said about `CheckboxSelectMultiple` but you can do without it. `RadioSelect` is actually needed for radio buttons. You can place checkboxes and radio buttons after their labels using Bootstrap horizontal form layout.

```
class SortFieldsForm(forms.Form):
    price_order=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=(('lowest', 'Lowest first'), ('highest',  'Highest first')))
    newest_entry=forms.BooleanField(label="Latest date")
    latest_year=forms.BooleanField(label="Latest year")

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
    helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
    helper.layout = Layout(
        'price_order',
        'newest_entry',
        'latest_year',
        Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white'))
```

Try to do like this. I cannot guarantee if there is no typos but you can achieve your goals this way.

Also, check out links below:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/
- http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms

Learn about bootstrap and its classes.

Comment: please provide more explanation

Comment: @eagertoLearn provided

Comment: Thanks George, I will test this now!